# Remove metadata from existing Pdf using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, metadata, itext

I created a pdf and added a metadata into it and also encrypted it uisng iTextsharp library.
Now I want to remove the encryption from the pdf. I successfully did so using iTextSharp but was not able to remove the metadata that I added.
Can anyone please giude me how can I remove the metadata. Its urgent.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question is too short and lacks detail. Please read stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When removing meta data it is easiest to work directly with the `PdfReader` object. Once you do that you can write that back to disk. The code below is a full working C# 2010 WinForms application targeting iTextSharp 5.1.2.0. It first creates a PDF with some meta data, then it modifies an in-memory version of the PDF using a `PdfReader`, and finally writes the changes to disk. See the code for additional comments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //File with meta data added
            string InputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");
            //File with meta data removed
            string OutputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");

            //Create a file with meta data, nothing special here
            using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)) {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)) {
                        Doc.Open();
                        Doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test"));
                        //Add a standard header
                        Doc.AddTitle("This is a test");
                        //Add a custom header
                        Doc.AddHeader("Test Header", "This is also a test");
                        Doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Read our newly created file
            PdfReader R = new PdfReader(InputFile);
            //Loop through each piece of meta data and remove it
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> KV in R.Info) {
                R.Info.Remove(KV.Key);
            }

            //The code above modifies an in-memory representation of the PDF, we need to write these changes to disk now
            using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (Document Doc = new Document()) {
                    //Use the PdfCopy object to copy each page
                    using (PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(Doc, FS)) {
                        Doc.Open();
                        //Loop through each page
                        for (int i = 1; i <= R.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                            //Add it to the new document
                            writer.AddPage(writer.GetImportedPage(R, i));
                        }
                        Doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added additional meatadata information. I first removed the metadata using reader and then added the metadata by setting moreinfo property of stamper. But the metadata value is still there.